# ruby on rails regex involving new line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string, replace, wildcard

My project is a Ruby on Rails project with rails version 5.1.2

I have a model called `CannedResponse` that has attributes `name` and `response` that are both strings. To create a canned response with name "ABC" and response

```
A

B

C
```

such that each of "A", "B","C" is situated on a new line, I enter as it is on the form. In the database/rails console I can see `CannedResponse.find_by_name("ABC").response` is returning `"A\r\nB\r\nC"`

All good so far.

Then I have another model `Message` that has attribute `body` in the form of a string. I want when a canned response is clicked, a javascript(using jQuery) will populate the message form's body part automatically with the response of the canned response. For example, on the page with message creation form which also has a list of canned responses beside it, I click the "ABC" canned response, the body part of the Message form is automatically populated with

```
A

B

C
```

This is working fine on the front end using this code:

```
$('#canned-response-response').val("<%== escape_javascript @canned_response.response %>");
let response = $('#canned-response-response').val()
$('#message-body-text').val(response);
```

Then I clicked 'create' and saw this happening in the log:

`INSERT INTO "messages" ("account_id", "to", "from", "body", "created_at", "updated_at", "service_provider_id", "read", "user_id", "ticket_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["account_id", 7], ["to", "16046140460"], ["from", "16477298395"], ["body", "A\nB\nC"],`.

The "body" params has become `"A\nB\nC"` instead of `"A\r\nB\r\nC"`(which is what the canned response's response really is).

As a result, when I do `Message.where('body LIKE ?, "%#{canned_response.response}%")` I'm getting none. But `Message.where('body LIKE ?, "%#{"A\nB\nC"}%")` will return something.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Do you want to search in the full message with equality across multiple lines? The likelihood of a full match will be very small. A full text search, either via an external solution or using the fulltext search capabilities of your DB of choice might be more appropriate than a `LIKE` search?

Comment: A possible workaround could be `Message.where('body LIKE ?, '%#{canned_response.response.gsub("\r",""}%)` and you could simplify this with a method in `CannedResponse` that does this... `def clean_response;response.gsub("\r","");end` and just use `clean_response` in your query.